# Android Studio gives error on local internet

Tags: android, kotlin

Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.5.31', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android', version: '1.5.31', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:

- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android:org.jetbrains.kotlin.android.gradle.plugin:1.5.31')
  Searched in the following repositories:
  Gradle Central Plugin Repository
  Google

Comment: Welcome! Please, post your build.gradle file - it will be helpful to identify the cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**- First Way:-**

Check your Internet connection and make sure your Internet is not restricted.

I solved this problem by turning on proxy for all tunnels (not just HTTP) with a VPN app.

**If not worked above way please try to second one**

**- Second Way**

```
 import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
//    kotlin("jvm") version "1.2.71"
}

group = "com.test"
version = "1.0-Test"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
}

//tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
//    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.8"
//}
```

- gradle sync by commenting on the above lines. The gradle will be set up.
- once the gradle is downloaded, uncomment those lines and sync again.
- if the dependencies are not downloaded properly, run 'gradle build' in the terminal and click on gradle sync.